# Angular directive - isolated scope isn't showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I trying to make a directive which accepting an attribute and hook it to the isolated scope, but the attribute value is not showing.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('torrentController', [function() {
    this.recommended = ['...'],
    this.otherArray = ['...']
}])
.directive('torrentsTable', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/directives/torrentsTable.html',
        scope: {
            index: '='
        },
        controller: 'torrentController as torrentCtrl'
    };
}]);
```

The idea is to use this directive to show different list of torrents with this syntax:

```
<torrents-table index="recommended"></torrents-table>
<torrents-table index="someOtherIndex"></torrents-table>
```

I wish this 2 almost same lines to show different "list" with results.

**`templates/directives/torrentsTable.html`**

```
<!-- I also tried with ng-repeat="torrent in torrentCtrl.recommended" -->
<!-- And is working as I excepted (It's shows the recommended array) -->

<div layout="row" ng-repeat="torrent in torrentCtrl[index]">
    <div flex>Name: {{torrent.name}}</div>
    <div flex>{{index}}</div>
</div>
```

`{{index}}` is not showing, and it's value is not showing.
While I actually make hardcoded `ng-repeat` arguments - it repeating but `{{index}}` is empty.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide minimal working sample, how you try it? i think you do one of the two mistakes, but not sure what

Comment: I just maded it! you already answered but anyway: http://jsbin.com/fihufifego/edit?html,output -- I will check your answer now.

Comment: yep :-) that what about i say in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem: how you pass key.

You use in directive:

```
scope: {
    index: '='
},
```

so you should pass to directive expression, that evaluated to `$scope` property. So if you not inject scope - you pass *undefined*.

You can fix this two ways:
1) pass string instead something else

```
<torrents-table index="'recommended'"></torrents-table>
<torrents-table index="'someOtherIndex'"></torrents-table>
```

2) change directive definition to

```
scope: {
    index: '@'
},
```

sample you can see in snippet below.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('torrentController', [function() {
    this.recommended = [1,2,3,4,5];
    this.someOtherIndex = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
}])
.directive('torrentsTable', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div flex>{{index}}</div>'+
                  '<div layout="row" ng-repeat="torrent in torrentCtrl[index]">'+
                  '  <div flex>Name: {{torrent}}</div>'+
                  '</div>',
        scope: {
            index: '='
        },
        controller: 'torrentController as torrentCtrl'
    };
}])
.directive('torrentsTable2', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div flex>{{index}}</div>'+
                  '<div layout="row" ng-repeat="torrent in torrentCtrl[index]">'+
                  '  <div flex>Name: {{torrent}}</div>'+
                  '</div>',
        scope: {
            index: '@'
        },
        controller: 'torrentController as torrentCtrl'
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <torrents-table index="'recommended'"></torrents-table>
  <torrents-table index="'someOtherIndex'"></torrents-table>  
  <hr/>
  <torrents-table2 index="recommended"></torrents-table2>
  <torrents-table2 index="someOtherIndex"></torrents-table2>  
</div>
```

Comment: So it's all about just one character `'=' to '@'` Jeez. Thank you.